# Better algorithm for searching through an array of points?

Tags: arrays, c, search, c11

I have an array of structs, where each struct is a 2D position (pair of 32-bit values). This array is for tracking points of interest on a map.

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

// ...

struct Point pointsOfInterest[1024];
```

The problem is, those points of interest are constantly changing, meaning the entries in the array are very frequently being added or removed. On top of that, each reported point of interest can possibly already exist in the array, so I can't blindly add new ones without checking whether they already exist.

At the moment the array is unsorted (new entries added to the end, swap and pop to remove), and I iterate over the entire list to find entries for removal or duplication check. I'd like to know what my options are for speeding up this process.

- In other languages, this is where I break out a dictionary or hash set. Neither exist in C, so I have to weigh the complexity of adding something like that.
- I've considered sorting the list (i.e. first by X, then Y). But given the frequency of updates, I feel like I'll be thrashing the table far more than when iterating. But my knowledge of sorting algorithms is minimal.
- Would a binary tree of some sort be any better here? Or would I again be spending all of my time re-balancing the tree?
- Theoretically, given the (perceived) complexity of these algorithms, is there a threshold below which a linear search remains a viable option?

I'm assuming this is a known solved problem, so I'm hoping to get pointed in the right direction before I spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel and testing possible solutions.

Comment: How many of these points are you expecting to have? The "threshold" is determined by profiling and can vary from system to system and depends on the concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from trivial cases, it's often extremely hard to predict where the performance gains are. That's why you should benchmark your code before and after changes. Also profile your code to find where it spends most time.

> In other languages, this is where I break out a dictionary or hash set. Neither exist in C, so I have to weigh the complexity of adding something like that.

TBH, it's not that complicated to implement. If you need the performance, it's a no brainer. But it's not guaranteed that it will be faster.

> I've considered sorting the list (i.e. first by X, then Y). But given the frequency of updates, I feel like I'll be thrashing the table far more than when iterating. But my knowledge of sorting algorithms is minimal.

It's very likely that this is not optimal. But you can try it out. And you don't need to do a complete sort. Just do a binary search and move everything that comes after.

> Would a binary tree of some sort be any better here? Or would I again be spending all of my time re-balancing the tree?

Only one way to find out. Try it and benchmark.

> Theoretically, given the (perceived) complexity of these algorithms, is there a threshold below which a linear search remains a viable option?

I'm sure there are, but these always have to be balanced with reality. Like cache misses that can have a great impact on performance. One thing that might improve cache-friendlyness could be changing

```
struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Point pointsOfInterest[1024];
```

to

```
int pointsOfInterest[2][1024];
```

And use the first index for x or y. Might work, depending on what you're doing with the data. I guess it would not work in your case, but it could speed up a function that's only loops over one dimension.

Comment: How exactly would changing to the `int` array improve cache performance? Now you'll have to touch two different `1024*sizeof(int)` chunks with each (x,y) access instead of staying inside the same cache line. Which would give far worse cache performance.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, in this case it will most likely be worse. But if you in some cases ONLY are interested in EITHER x or y, it could improve things.